# Can't process json sent by jquery ajax

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I can't seem to get the following to work

```
restoJSON = { "name" : "Bloesem", "qName" : "bloesem", "address" : "Binnen Dommersstraat 13", "area" : "Jordaan", "tel" : "770 0407", "cuisine" : "European", "comment" : "Ver``rassingsmenu - slow service but 'gezellig' atmosphere", "booking" : "", "website" : "http://www.restaurantbloesem.nl/", "link" : "/?p=6", "rating" : 3, "price" : "3", "lat" : "52.382917", "lng" : "4.8854370000000245", "heading" : "0", "pitch" : "0", "zoom" : "0" };

     jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "updateDatabase.php",
       data: restoJSON,
       dataType: "text",
       success: function(response, stat)
       {
         console.log("Response: " + response);
       },
       error: function()
        {
           console.log(arguments);
        }       
     });
```

and then updateDatatbase.php has variations on these lines for debugging

```
echo "name: " . $_POST['qName'];
$json = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
echo " " . $json['qName'];
foreach($_POST as $key=>$val) {
echo $key . "-x-" . $val;
}
```

I'm a relative nooby and getting stuff done by copying suggestions from this forum, rather than fully understanding. Console log is below - *note how it has split the = in the link line*.

```
Response: name: 
{"name":"Bloesem",
"qName":"bloesem",
"address":"Binnen_Dommersstraat_13",
"area":"Jordaan",
"tel":"770_0407",
"cuisine":"European",
"comment":"Verrassingsmenu_-_slow_service_but_'gezellig'_atmosphere",
"booking":"",
"website":"http://www_restaurantbloesem_nl/",
"link":"/?p-x-6\",
\"rating\" : 3,
\"price\" : \"3\",
\"lat\" : \"52.382917\",
\"lng\" : \"4.8854370000000245\",
\"heading\" : \"0\",
\"pitch\" : \"0\",
\"zoom\" : \"0\"
}
```

Comment: you might want to just use $.post() to simplify the process

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your code your echoing two strings. You need to remove one of them, most likely the `echo $query;`

So try changing:

```
echo "name: " . $json['qName'];
echo $query;
```

to just:

```
echo "name: " . $json['qName'];
```

Your also missing a semicolon at the end of `restoJSON` and its not being declared a variable using `var`.

Change this:

```
restoJSON = { "name" : "Bloesem", "qName" : "bloesem", "address" : "Binnen Dommersstraat 13", "area" : "Jordaan", "tel" : "770 0407", "cuisine" : "European", "comment" : "Ver``rassingsmenu - slow service but 'gezellig' atmosphere", "booking" : "", "website" : "http://www.restaurantbloesem.nl/", "link" : "/?p=6", "rating" : 3, "price" : "3", "lat" : "52.382917", "lng" : "4.8854370000000245", "heading" : "0", "pitch" : "0", "zoom" : "0" }
```

To:

```
var restoJSON = { "name" : "Bloesem", "qName" : "bloesem", "address" : "Binnen Dommersstraat 13", "area" : "Jordaan", "tel" : "770 0407", "cuisine" : "European", "comment" : "Ver``rassingsmenu - slow service but 'gezellig' atmosphere", "booking" : "", "website" : "http://www.restaurantbloesem.nl/", "link" : "/?p=6", "rating" : 3, "price" : "3", "lat" : "52.382917", "lng" : "4.8854370000000245", "heading" : "0", "pitch" : "0", "zoom" : "0" };
```

And last of all your sending your data as `key/value` pairs so there is no reason to `json_decode()` them.

Change this:

```
$json = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
```

To:

```
$json = $_POST;
```

Answer (score 0):

When the data is sent via jQuery.ajax the POST variables are set to the keys/values in restoJSON. So, in the PHP there is no need for the JSON decoding. Just simply do:

```
echo "name: " . $_POST['qName'];
```

To see that 'qName' was passed through. Also, it looks like your UPDATE statement is not currently setting any fields at the moment (see: [PHP Update Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)).

Comment: Is the fact that I am passing sentences and special characters causing a problem do you think?

Comment: That should not be a problem, as long as the characters are escaped (if needed). Are you looking at the POST request as well, to make sure the data is being sent correctly? It looks like restoJSON is being passed as a string to the jQuery.ajax instead of an object based on the output you posted. Which is why the '=' is replaced by '-x-'.

Comment: OK, so I gave up with JSON and : separators and "" around content. Now I'm using = and escape() and all works. I feel like I have missed something, but the end result works